# easySlider 1.7 undefined is not a function?

Tags: jquery, easyslider

I'm new with jQuery and it's pretty much my first time implementing jQuery coding into my layouts. I'm using Dreamweaver which was fine and dandy, nothing was wrong with the coding & easySlider was working perfectly fine. It was only when I uploaded it online that my script didn't work.

Been searching all over this site as I saw some people with the same problems, but I tried out all that's been said & it still didn't work. So I'm hoping someone can help me out here!

Here's the error message:

```
scripts.js:10TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#slider").easySlider')
```

Here's my code:

```
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/easyslider1.7/js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/scripts.js"></script>

</head>

...

<div id="slider">
    <ul>

    <li><img src="images/scroll9.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><img src="images/scroll2.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><img src="images/scroll3.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#slider ul, #slider li{
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }

#slider, #slider li{ 
    width: 1018px;
    height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    }

    span#prevBtn{}
    span#nextBtn{}
```

and my scripts.js:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider").easySlider({
                    controlsShow: false,
                    auto: 'true',
                    continuous: 'true',
                    prevText: '',
                    nextText: '',
                    speed: 500,
                    pause: 4000

    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your jquery / easySlider js files are in the directory you specified in the `<head>` - use something liek Firebug to check they are downloaded correctly - see the network tab

Comment: Yay! Thanks so much :) I didn't see the /js/ between the easysliders!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your jquery / easySlider js files are in the directory you specified in the `<head>` - use something like Firebug to check they are downloaded correctly - see the network tab